# Change number of rows in a listview display

Tags: android, xml, listview

How would i change the number of rows displayed in a list view ?

[image]

I want to show three items in the listview and then have it be scrollable.
I know i can hard code the listview height but is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the height of a row after it's added then change the height of the listview to be 3*height. You need to do all of this after the list is rendered though.

example:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    String[] names = new String[] {"hi", "my", "name", "is", "slim", "shady"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, names);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    View row = listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, listView);
    row.measure(0, 0);
    int rowHeight = row.getMeasuredHeight();
    listView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, rowHeight*3));
```

Comment: I tried that already

`int height = 3 * (LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.review_list_item, null)).getHeight();
                listView.setMinimumHeight(height);`
but it didnt work. im not sure why

Comment: You need to check the height after the list is rendered:
        View row = listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, listView);
        row.measure(0, 0);
        int rowHeight = row.getMeasuredHeight();
        listView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, rowHeight*3));

Comment: define a custom row for inflating the listView, define the viewgroup widgets like : TextView, TmageView, EditText in the custom row. and then set the height for the row to wrap content, it will help solving the requirement.

you can also [see  this tutorial](http://blog.lovelyhq.com/setting-listview-height-depending-on-the-items/)